# How to get removed document in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to get the document that was removed from MongoDB?

```
result = db.things.remove({_id: id})
// is there a result.removedObjects?
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is possible, but it requires a different command. You are looking for the [`findAndModify` command](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/findAndModify+Command).

If you set the options to `{query: ..., remove: true, new: false}`, you will delete a single document and return the removed document.

*Some notes*:

- `new` is a keyword in many languages, ensure that you are wrapping the text of the flag correctly.
- the `findAndModify` will only work with a single document. This is fine for deleting `_id` but not good for ranged removes.

Comment: Isn't the `new` parameter ignored when `remove: true`? found it in the [node-mongodb-native docs](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native#find-and-modify) and [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/)

Comment: Quite possible that it is ignored. Those docs were written about 12 months after this answer was written :) That stated, you're probably right, the `new` flag is likely ignored given that the return value would be the same either way.

Comment: How do we go about returning range of documents that match condition after removing ?

Comment: It gives me error "User.findAndModify is not a function"

Answer (score 3):

```
db.collection('mycollection').findOneAndDelete({
    id: '123456'
}, function (error, response) {
    response.value;// returns the deleted object, but no longer exists in the database
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!