# Removing doc and reading its fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb

In my app I need a function that removes docs and giving me the removed doc fields. The docs for the driver are not clear about the callback of `deleteMany`. It returns a result that is `deleteWriteOpResultObject`. I don't know how to get the deleted doc fields from that.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11607487/how-to-get-removed-document-in-mongodb) will be helpful.

Comment: Are you looking for a function to remove multiple docs or just a single doc?

Comment: Multiple docs and receiving their fields

Answer (score 0):

You may use [findAndModify](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/) operation with `remove: true` and `fields: {your_fields}` if you need to get and delete a single document. In case you have to remove and select multiple records, you may execute `findAndModify` multiple times or call `find`, wait the results and `remove` them all by IDs.

Comment: Isn't there a more efficient way then looping through each doc or find query and then remove query.

Comment: @h.Oo No, there's not. BTW, why do you think `find` + `remove` is not efficient? It may look a little more clumsy than a single operation, but it causes no performance issues.