# Mongodb + Node.js: delete multiple documents and return them

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm using the below code to delete multiple documents at once:

```
db.collection('testcollection').deleteMany({
    id: {
        $in: ['1', '2', '3']
    }
}, function (error, response) {
    // ...
});
```

Is there a way to delete and return all the deleted documents in one go?

**NOTE**: I'm looking for ***multiple* delete and *multiple* return**, which is different than this question: [How to get removed document in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11607487/how-to-get-removed-document-in-mongodb)

Comment: AFAIK, you can't do that. Fetch the required objects first and then delete

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, [`deleteMany()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#deleteMany) passes only the [error](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/MongoError.html) and [deleteWriteOpResult](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#~deleteWriteOpResult) to your callback so no actual documents are passed.

This is not just with Node.js - this is how actually [`db.collection.deleteMany`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.deleteMany/) works in Mongo:

> Returns:  A document containing:
>
> - A boolean acknowledged as true if the
>     operation ran with write concern or false if write concern was
>     disabled
> - deletedCount containing the number of deleted documents

You have to do it with two requests, but you can abstract it away in a single function - e.g. if you're using the [native Mongo driver](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/index.html) you can write something like this:

```
function getAndDelete(collectionName, filter, callback) {
  var collection = db.collection(collectionName);
  collection.find(filter, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      callback(err);
    } else {
      collection.deleteMany(filter, function (err, r) {
        if (err) {
          callback(err);
        } else {
          callback(null, data);
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

that you can call with:

```
getAndDelete('testcollection', {
    id: {
        $in: ['1', '2', '3']
    }
}, function (error, response) {
    // ...
});
```

This code is not tested but just to give you an idea where to start from.

Note: there used to be [`findAndRemove()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#findAndRemove) but it's been deprecated.

Comment: I have the same issue and with this approach you can get conflicting results.The moment your `.find()` is completed and has send you back the results another operation may have changed some of the documents. If you then `.deleteMany()` using the same filter used for `.find()` you could be removing different documents than the documents you found initially with `.find()`. Solve this by doing `collection.find(filter, projection = {_id:true}, function (err,data)` and create a new filter for `.deleteMany({_id: {"$in": [.find()_id's]}})` (the projection is because you don't need other attributes)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a simple way for achieving this task.We can use async and await concept,this is make the code less complicated.

```
const getDeletedData = async(filter) => {
        const products = await collection.find({filter});
        await collection.deleteMany({filter});

     return products;
    }
```

then you can call getDeletedData({name : "xyz"}) with the filter.