# MongoDB: How to remove all documents matching a query and return their ids

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

With MongoDB, is it possible to specify a query and removes all matching documents while returning the documents' ids (alternatively the whole document)?

I found "[How to get removed document in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11607666/615306)" that explains how remove a **single** document and return it using `findAndModify`. However, I need to remove a bunch of documents at once.

I'm ok with a solution involving the aggregation pipeline as long as it fulfils the requirements.

I'm using the offical C# driver, but solutions in JS are ok.

Comment: Would this answer help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40844214/mongodb-node-js-delete-multiple-documents-and-return-them ?

Comment: So fetch first and delete in a second command?

Comment: Yep, it is the simplest way. Just make sure you select by filter, and delete by ids. Otherwise, if you delete by filter, there are chances to delete something different from what you have selected, if concurrent requests change selected documents.